# Number of text input along with image file from Angularjs HTTP POST to PHP server page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am posting some data to a php server page from angularjs controller using the $http. I'm getting result when passing one text field one image file, But I didn't get second text field result.

What I did show below

HTML code

```
<tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="event_year" id="event_year" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="title" id="title"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <td><input type="file" file-model="myFile"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#/home" style="text-decoration: none;"><input type="button" ng-model="cancel" value="Cancel"/></a></td>
    <td><button ng-click="uploadFile()">Submit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Angularjs controller

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
   };
}]); 

app.controller('v7Controller', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

   $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);

        var uploadUrl = "pages/actionFile.php";
        /*var text = $scope.event_year;*/ // i'm getting this result 
         var text = {"year" : $scope.event_year,"title" : $scope.title};
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, text);
   };

}]);




app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, name){

         var fd = new FormData();
         fd.append('file', file);
         fd.append('name', name);
         $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}
         })
         .success(function(data){
            console.log("Success"+data);
         })
         .error(function(){
            console.log("Success");
         }); 
     }
 }]);
```

Php server page

```
<?php

     $target_dir = "../images/";
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     //print_r($name);

     print_r($_FILES);
     $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
     echo json_encode($_FILES["file"]); // new file uploaded
     //echo $name;

?>
```

File is successfully insert in the folder, But I didn't take other text values I'm new in angularjs. Please help.. Thanks a lot